# How to send Response or status of request using springboot-rest api

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, response

I have two rest webservice in my applcation as below(using spring-boot rest api)

1- public **void processRequest(Request)** - This is asynch webservice to process the request, This will return id of request to client with acknowledgement.

2- public **Response getResponse(jobid)** - This webservice should return the response of the request generated by ProcessRequest.
here i want to send the status if request is not ready yet.

Is there any way to achieve above requirement?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far, thanks

Comment: Have a look at`HttpClient`. You can use `sendAsync` to call `processRequest`. Once the `id` is returned, you can call `getResponse(jobId)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the request id in database and wait for the response by polling the database.

Like the request api may be in wait state and the response api will update the db with the request id

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).